# How to remove escaped characters from a path returned by NSSavePanel::url::path?

Tags: swift, macos, nssavepanel

I'm using the following to let a user pick a file to save in my macOS app:

```
let panel = NSSavePanel()
let resp = panel.runModal()
if(resp == .OK)
{
    let strFilePath = panel.url?.path();
}
```

The problem is that `NSSavePanel::url::path` escapes spaces (and possibly other characters) in a path. So instead of:

> /Users/user/Documents/file 2.txt

I'm getting:

> /Users/user/Documents/file%202.txt

So how do I get it to return the former path?

Comment: i think you want to get `lastpathcompnent` and play with it. because it will proper file name.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it, but I'm not sure why `path()` returns those escaped sequences? `let strFilePath = panel.url?.path().removingPercentEncoding;`

Comment: that sequences represent space as per my understanding. because i face it alot. `space` = `%20` in path.

Comment: It represents a space in a URL but not in a POSIX file path.